# Blur / Focus com Jquey

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo um projeto que tem diversos inputs, porém só posso digitar em apenas 2 deles, por isso gostaria de que meu jquery fizesse uma validação para que o usuário possa apenas entrar nesses campos, algo como isso:

```
 $("#FL1").on('blur', function () {
    if(campo == 1){
        return;
    }
    else 
        $("#FL1").focus();
 });

 $("#FL2").on('blur', function () {
    campo = 0;
 });
```

Existe alguma forma de fazer algo deste tipo?

Comment: Colocando o input como **readonly** não resolve seu problema? Se não, o que você deseja ao usuário clicar no input que não pode, ele deverá ser direcionado para outro input?

Comment: Não resolve o meu problema colocá-lo como **readonly**. Eu teria um input principal, que sempre que eu clicar em outro lugar ele vai retornar para ele, mas gostaria que desse input eu pudesse entrar em outro para o usuário poder digitar no segundo input também.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi muito bem o que deseja, mas se você não quer deixar o usuário digitar nada em alguns inputs, você pode utilizar o próprio evento [.focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) para isso.

Para isso, basta adicionar os inputs que não podem ser digitado, e no evento `focus`, redirecione-o para o input principal.

Um exemplo seria assim:

```js
$('.ignore').focus(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#fl1').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Principal:
<input id="fl1" />
<br/>
<br/>Ignorar:
<input class="ignore" />
<br/>Ignorar:
<input class="ignore" />
<br/>Ignorar:
<input class="ignore" />
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>Secundario:
<input id="fl2" />
```

Dessa forma, todos os inputs com a classe **ignore** será direcionado para o input com o id **fl1**.

#### Edição

Com base nos comentários, podemos usar a mesma analogia, porém a inverso. Usaremos `document` como seletor, e se não for os input's que podem ter acesso, faça o foco ir para o que deseja, dessa forma:

```js
$(document).click(function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest(".ignore").length) {
    $('#fl1').focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Principal:
<input id="fl1" class="ignore" />
<br/>
<br/>Ignorar:
<input />
<br/>Ignorar:
<input />
<br/>Ignorar:
<input />
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>Secundario:
<input id="fl2" class="ignore" />
```

Para maiores informações, pode olhar [esta resposta.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10851375/4843158)

Comment: Se não for isso que procura, favor explicar melhor que altero a resposta.

Comment: Ficou meio redundante a pergunta mesmo, não faz sentido ter campo na tela já que não irá utiliza-los.

Comment: Muito obrigado, seria basicamente isso que eu quero, porém quando eu clico fora dos inputs ele perde o focus do campo, como posso fazer para que isso não ocorra? A pergunta talvez tenha ficado ruim pois não seriam outros inputs que tenho na tela, na verdade não quero que perca o focus do campo quando eu clicar na tela fora dos meus inputs...

Comment: @gabriel veja se isso resolve seu problema.

Comment: Foi exatamente isso que acabei de fazer no meu código... Muito obrigado @Randrade peja ajuda. Abraço!

Comment: @gabriel Por nada. Aproveitando, faça o [tour] para entender melhor como o site funciona. Você pode votar e/ou aceitar a resposta caso lhe ajudou. Caso tenha encontrado uma opção melhor, pode postar também para ajudar os demais.